# BigQuery - convert scientific notation to decimal format

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
SELECT 
    SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue) *0.20 AS COGS
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170701';
```

Why does BigQuery automatically convert the created field 'Cost Of Goods Sold - COGS' to scientific notation?
and how can i amend this query to pull the COGS as a decimal format value?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: My guess would be to first convert `totals.totalTransactionRevenue` to decimal. The guess here is that attribute is a `float`.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but if you're calling Big Query from a presentation layer, then worry about formatting there.

Comment: @HoneyBadger how can i do this in the same query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the new numeric/decimal value to get the format you want:

```
SELECT cast(SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue) * 0.20 as numeric) AS COGS
```

It also works to cast as a string:

```
SELECT cast(SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue) * 0.20 as string) AS COGS
```

Comment: Thanks again, Gordon. That worked. Any idea why does BigQuery automatically convert the sum() * 0.20 into scientific notation when just the sum() is displayed as a numeric?

Comment: @AdilK . . . I honestly have no idea at all.  So far, I haven't experienced this, except when I ran your query.  We do still use floats for some numeric values; perhaps the sums have not (yet) gotten to 100,000,000.